# zip method to iterate over two lists simultaneously in C?

Tags: c, list, for-loop

I have two lists with 14 elements each, I created using the following code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/cpl_conv.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


// Node Structure of Linked-List
typedef struct nlist{
    char *data;
    struct nlist *next;
}Node;

//Declaring global variables
Node *B02_list;
Node *SCL_list;


// Function to replace a string with another 
// string 
char* str_replace(char* string, const char* substr, const char* replacement) {
    char* tok = NULL;
    char* newstr = NULL;
    char* oldstr = NULL;
    int   oldstr_len = 0;
    int   substr_len = 0;
    int   replacement_len = 0;

    newstr = strdup(string);
    substr_len = strlen(substr);
    replacement_len = strlen(replacement);

    if (substr == NULL || replacement == NULL) {
        return newstr;
    }

    while ((tok = strstr(newstr, substr))) {
        oldstr = newstr;
        oldstr_len = strlen(oldstr);
        newstr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (oldstr_len - substr_len + replacement_len + 1));

        if (newstr == NULL) {
            free(oldstr);
            return NULL;
        }

        memcpy(newstr, oldstr, tok - oldstr);
        memcpy(newstr + (tok - oldstr), replacement, replacement_len);
        memcpy(newstr + (tok - oldstr) + replacement_len, tok + substr_len, oldstr_len - substr_len - (tok - oldstr));
        memset(newstr + oldstr_len - substr_len + replacement_len, 0, 1);

        free(oldstr);
    }

    free(string);

    return newstr;
}


// Function to insert an element to the Linked-List
Node* insert(Node *Head, char *value)
{
    Node *new_string;
    new_string = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_string->data = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
    strcpy(new_string->data,value);
    Node *check;
    check = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(Head == NULL){
        Head = new_string;
        Head->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        check = Head;
        while(check->next != NULL)
            check = check->next;

        check->next = new_string;
        new_string->next = NULL;
    }
    return Head;
}


//Function to check if a string finishes with a suffix
int string_ends_with(const char * str, const char * suffix)
{
    int str_len = strlen(str);
    int suffix_len = strlen(suffix);

    return 
        (str_len >= suffix_len) &&
        (0 == strcmp(str + (str_len-suffix_len), suffix));
}


//Function to show the elements of the Linked-List
void show(Node *Head)
{
    if (Head == NULL){
        return;
    }

    while(Head != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", Head->data);
        Head=Head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Function to find the files in a directory based on a wildcard
Node * recurList(char *basePath, char *suffix)
{
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent *dp;

    DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "/");
           strcat(path, dp->d_name);

        struct stat s;
            if (stat(path, &s) == 0)
            {
                if( s.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
                {
                recurList(path, suffix);
                }
                else if(s.st_mode &S_IFREG)
                {
                if (string_ends_with(path, suffix))
                    B02_list = insert(B02_list, path);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    return B02_list;
    closedir(dir);
}

//Function to find the SCL files in a directory 
Node * recurListSCL(char *basePath, char *suffix)
{
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent *dp;

    DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "/");
           strcat(path, dp->d_name);

        struct stat s;
            if (stat(path, &s) == 0)
            {
                if( s.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
                {
                recurListSCL(path, suffix);
                }
                else if(s.st_mode &S_IFREG)
                {
                if (string_ends_with(path, suffix))
                    SCL_list = insert(SCL_list, path);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    return SCL_list;
    closedir(dir);
}

int getCount(Node* head)
{
    int count = 0;
    Node * current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        count ++;
        current = current ->next;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    char path[100];
    char suffix[100];

    printf("Enter path to list files: ");
    scanf("%s", path);
    printf("Enter the wildcard: ");
    scanf("%s", suffix);

    Node *B02;
    Node *SCL;
    B02 = recurList(path, suffix);
    printf("Printing B02_head!\n");
    show(B02);
    char *suffix_scl = "SCL_10m.tif";
    SCL = recurListSCL(path, suffix_scl);
    printf("Printing files in SCL head:\n");
    show(SCL);
    int B02_length = 0;
    int SCL_length = 0;
    B02_length = getCount(B02);
    SCL_length = getCount(SCL);
    printf("BO2 of length: %d\n", B02_length);
    printf("SCL of length: %d\n", SCL_length);

    printf("TESTING FOR LOOP\n");
    Node *index;
    Node *index_scl;
    int ctr = 0;
    for ((index = B02) && (index_scl = SCL);
    (index !=NULL) & (index_scl !=NULL); 
    index=index->next, index_scl->next)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ctr);
        ctr++;
        printf("B02 element is:\n%s\n", index->data);
        printf("SCL element is:\n%s\n", index_scl->data);
        printf("-------------------------------\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to iterate in the main() function over the two lists I created. However the code gives me the following output, after compilation.

```
Enter path to list files: data
Enter the wildcard: B02_10m.tif
Printing B02_head!
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180816T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180816T213001.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016453_20180816T155524/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180816T155521_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180925T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180925T204924.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017025_20180925T155550/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180925T155521_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180727T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180727T204908.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016167_20180727T155526/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180727T155531_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180217T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180217T221531.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A013879_20180217T160029/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180217T155521_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180617T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180617T204705.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A015595_20180617T155525/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180617T155531_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180806T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180806T204419.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016310_20180806T155756/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180806T155531_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180309T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180309T204813.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014165_20180309T155521/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180309T155521_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181224T155521_N0207_R011_T17PLK_20181224T191439.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A018312_20181224T155529/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181224T155521_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180508T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180508T223957.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A015023_20180508T155528/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180508T155531_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181124T155521_N0207_R011_T17PLK_20181124T191524.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017883_20181124T155518/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181124T155521_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2B_MSIL2A_20180113T155519_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180113T190318.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A004470_20180113T160002/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180113T155519_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2B_MSIL2A_20180103T155519_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180103T221514.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A004327_20180103T160032/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180103T155519_B02_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181025T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20181025T192616.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017454_20181025T155522/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181025T155521_B02_10m.tif

Printing files in SCL head:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180816T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180816T213001.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016453_20180816T155524/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180816T155521_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180925T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180925T204924.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017025_20180925T155550/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180925T155521_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180727T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180727T204908.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016167_20180727T155526/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180727T155531_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180217T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180217T221531.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A013879_20180217T160029/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180217T155521_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180617T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180617T204705.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A015595_20180617T155525/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180617T155531_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180806T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180806T204419.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016310_20180806T155756/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180806T155531_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180309T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180309T204813.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014165_20180309T155521/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180309T155521_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181224T155521_N0207_R011_T17PLK_20181224T191439.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A018312_20181224T155529/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181224T155521_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180508T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180508T223957.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A015023_20180508T155528/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180508T155531_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181124T155521_N0207_R011_T17PLK_20181124T191524.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017883_20181124T155518/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181124T155521_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2B_MSIL2A_20180113T155519_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180113T190318.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A004470_20180113T160002/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180113T155519_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2B_MSIL2A_20180103T155519_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180103T221514.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A004327_20180103T160032/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180103T155519_SCL_10m.tif
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181025T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20181025T192616.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017454_20181025T155522/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181025T155521_SCL_10m.tif

BO2 of length: 14
SCL of length: 14
TESTING FOR LOOP
0
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

1
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180816T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180816T213001.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016453_20180816T155524/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180816T155521_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

2
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180925T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180925T204924.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017025_20180925T155550/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180925T155521_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

3
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180727T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180727T204908.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016167_20180727T155526/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180727T155531_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

4
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180217T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180217T221531.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A013879_20180217T160029/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180217T155521_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

5
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180617T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180617T204705.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A015595_20180617T155525/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180617T155531_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

6
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180806T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180806T204419.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A016310_20180806T155756/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180806T155531_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

7
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180309T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180309T204813.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014165_20180309T155521/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180309T155521_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

8
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181224T155521_N0207_R011_T17PLK_20181224T191439.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A018312_20181224T155529/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181224T155521_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

9
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180508T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180508T223957.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A015023_20180508T155528/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180508T155531_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

10
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181124T155521_N0207_R011_T17PLK_20181124T191524.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017883_20181124T155518/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181124T155521_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

11
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2B_MSIL2A_20180113T155519_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180113T190318.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A004470_20180113T160002/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180113T155519_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

12
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2B_MSIL2A_20180103T155519_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180103T221514.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A004327_20180103T160032/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180103T155519_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------

13
B02 element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20181025T155521_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20181025T192616.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A017454_20181025T155522/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20181025T155521_B02_10m.tif
SCL element is:
data/selected_files_l2a/S2A_MSIL2A_20180408T155531_N0206_R011_T17PLK_20180408T204658.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T17PLK_A014594_20180408T155557/IMG_DATA/R10m/T17PLK_20180408T155531_SCL_10m.tif
-------------------------------
```

I am just wondering if there is method to effectively iterate over two lists in C simultaneously, compared to the built-in methods in Python like zip?
[How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

My best try was the one in the code, but although I declared the scl_index in the next iteration it has to be the next value in the linked-list, it returns in every iteration the next value of B02 (which is the first desirable output), but sticks with the very first element of the second linked-list all the way until all elements of the first list are depleted.

Have anyone an idea about it. !?

Comment: That doesn't really look like a [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And if the code is working (very important) then perhaps this would be better of on the [Code Review SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: That's too much code for me to look through, but I would bet the problem stems from `index=index->next, index_scl->next` not doing what you think it does. `,` is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type); there is a sequence point between these evaluations.

Comment: The whole statement `for ((index = B02) && (index_scl = SCL); (index !=NULL) & (index_scl !=NULL); index=index->next, index_scl->next)` doesn't make much sense, and have some flaws that could lead to serious problems (and *undefined behavior*). So this is definitely not "working" and shouldn't be on the Code Review site.

Comment: The compiler should be generating a warning that tells you exactly what the problem is. What compiler are you using? What command line did you use to compile? And what was the output from the compiler?

Comment: I compile using cc <filename.c> -o filename -lgdal -Wall

Comment: It's true, I got the following warning: ```list_dir_files_5.c:228:24: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
     for ((index = B02) && (index_scl = SCL);
                        ^~
list_dir_files_5.c:230:23: warning: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     index=index->next , index_scl->next)
```

Comment: Yup, apparently you meant to write `index_scl = index_scl->next`, but omitted the assignment.

Comment: Note that while you're learning C, you should compile with `-Werror`. That way, you won't miss the warnings (because the compiler won't give you an executable until you fix all of the warnings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the for loop.

You should modify it to

```
for (index = B02,index_scl = SCL; 
    (index !=NULL) && (index_scl !=NULL); 
     index=index->next,index_scl = index_scl->next)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The bitwise AND `&` is probably supposed to be a logical AND `&&` as well.

Comment: I modified the code in that way, and it worked. I declared the index_scl within the the for loop, and then assigned the index_scl value to the next in the linked list, and works fine!

Comment: ```for (index = B02; index !=NULL; index=index->next)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ctr);
        ctr++;
        printf("B02 element is:\n%s\n", index->data);
        printf("SCL element is:\n%s\n", index_scl->data);
        index_scl = index_scl->next;
        printf("-------------------------------\n");
        printf("\n");
    }```

Comment: @RogerAlmengor - In the case you showed in the comment above, if `index_scl` has fewer elements than `index` you will dereference a NULL pointer and most probably get a seg fault.